# datepicker.ui header box too large

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am scratching my head on this one and I don't really know what code to show you as I don't have any code that directly effects this input but I will put anything I can think of.

I have a text input on an html form that is utilizing jquery datepicker.  I have seen this in use and it looks and works great but for some reason the top bar on my datepicker is WAY too big.  See normal version on the left and what is showing up for my program on the right:

[image: Normal]       [image: What I get]

**HTML:**

```
<input title="The last day the individual received a service" type="text" class="datepicker frm-field" id="last-service-date" name="last-service-date"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
.frm-field {
    display: block;
    background-color: #b6cce2;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1pt solid black;
    font-size: 12pt;
    padding-left: 4pt;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}

div.ui-datepicker{
    font-size: 12px;
}

input, select {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
  });
```

I have not altered any of the downloaded code I am just using it straight out of the box.  I apologize for the lack of information but I honestly am not sure what else could be causing this issue...

Thanks for any assistance you can offer!

**UPDATE**

using the following css code that Hackerman provided the box changed but does not take the content with it:

**CSS:**

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header { 
    position: relative; 
    padding: .2em 0; 
    height: 30px !Important; 
}
```

**Pic:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

New CSS code from Hackerman:

```
.ui-datepicker-month { 
    display: inline-block !Important; 
    width: 60px !Important; 
}
```

**Pic of results:**

[image]

Final Answer:

**Here is the CSS that fixed it:**

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header { 
    position: relative; 
    height: 22px !Important; 
}

.ui-datepicker-month { 
    display: inline-block !Important; 
}

.ui-datepicker-year { 
    display: inline-block !Important; 
}
```

**Pic of rendered datepicker:**

[image]

Thanks!!!!

Comment: why are you changing the font size of the datepicker?

Comment: Please give me a link to the datepicker site.

Comment: You can try this css rule: `.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header {
    position: relative;
    padding: .2em 0;
    height: 30px !Important;
}`

Comment: Changing the font-size is how the size of the datepicker itself is changed.  The entire pop up gets larger or smaller based on the font-size.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem the site is located on an internal server that I cannot open to the public...I wish I could

Comment: @Hackerman that code changed the size of the box but did not take the content with it.  I will post a pic of what was rendered so you can see.

Comment: ok I know that, but have you tried the datepicker without the font change?

Comment: @Maulzal I have tried omitting the font-size and it just makes the pop up very small but the top box stays ridiculously large

Comment: Another rule just for testing: `.ui-datepicker-month {
    display: inline-block !Important;
    width: 60px !Important;
}`

Comment: Hey Craig, could you add this to a JSFiddle, so we can play around with the code?

Comment: @Hackerman just updated the question with your suggestion and it is starting to come together!

Comment: @Hackerman you got me where I needed to go!  I have updated the question with the final solution.  Would you mind posting the answer so I can mark it completed?  Thanks!

Comment: @CraigHowell, done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using this fiddle for testing, in order to know the right css classes to modify:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/Fa8Xx/3999/

This way i start making somes changes, first on:

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header { 
  position: relative; 
  padding: .2em 0; 
  height: 30px !Important; 
}
```

And later on:

```
.ui-datepicker-month { 
  display: inline-block !Important; 
  width: 60px !Important; 
}
```

> I think the issue was caused due to css rules conflict between stylesheets.